# Why isn't Jacob Kowalski in Hogwarts a History?

Tags: harry-potter, the-secrets-of-dumbledore

Surely, Hermione would note a Muggle with a wand in Hogwarts.

Comment: The question as written seems to imply that Hermione wrote the book. For the sake of clarity, could you expand the question a bit.

Comment: I haven’t read *Hogwarts, a History* but are you sure he’s not in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Hermione's reactions (and remembering the fact that she read the book in its entirety before arriving at Hogwarts), this history misses a lot of interesting information about the school, such as the fact that House-Elves keep the school running. So it may be that the book leaves out material that is embarrassing to the Wizarding world - and the fact that a Muggle successfully used a wand may fit in that category.